# SweepGradient ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, sweepgradient

I create a `SweepGradient` like this

```
int[] colors = { Color.RED, Color.BLUE };
// float[] positions = {0,1}; => this will work without error
float[] positions = { 0 , 280f/360 };
SweepGradient gradient = new SweepGradient(width / 2, height / 2, colors, positions);
```

When I set `float[] positions = {0,1}`, it will work correctly (no error).
When I change to `float[] positions = { 0 , 280f/360 }`, in the `Preview mode of AndroidStudio` it displays an rendering error but in the simulator it works fine
Why this happend? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: the preview is inaccurate, an may render incorrectly. It is a common problem, and not going to be fixed soon. Just ignore  the preview errors until it works on the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int colors[] = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE};
    float positions[] = {0.f, 280f / 360, 1.f};
```

Make sure that the `positoins` array spans full range i.e. [0.f, 1.0f]. Now the preview will also be shown correctly.

Comment: I will check it, but I only want 2 colors not 3 three color. how can I achieve it

Comment: Please note that the last color is same as second-last color. That will show the constant color in that range. Could you please share the exact  expected result via image?

Answer (score 0):

May be NULL. The relative position of each corresponding color in the colors array, beginning  with 0 and ending with 1.0.